# Knockout js passing textbox value to viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I have  model class and viewmodel and I am creating an instance of the model class.

When i enter some text inside the input tag the value won't get into the viewmodel, when I click the "save" button I get an empty array.

HTML

```html
<div id="UserID">
    <lable>UserName</lable>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:currentUser().userName" />
    <br />
    <!--<span data-bind="text:firstName" /><br />-->
    <label>MobileNumber</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:currentUser().userMobileNumber" /><br />
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:currentUser().userEmail" /><br />
    <label>Image</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:currentUser().userImageBase64" /><br />
    <label>Image</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:currentUser().userImageType" /><br />
    <label>DeviceUID</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:currentUser().deviceUId" /><br />
    <input type="button" value="save" data-bind="click:currentUser().saveuserDetail" />
</div>
```

JS

```
// Model class///
var userModel = function() {
    self = this;
    self.userName = ko.observable()
    self.userMobileNumber = ko.observable();
    self.userEmail = ko.observable();
    self.userImageBase64 = ko.observable();
    self.userImageType = ko.observable();
    self.deviceUId = ko.observable();
}

//ViewModel//
var userDetails = function() {
    self = this;
    self.currentUser = ko.observable(new userModel());
    //ajax post
    self.saveuserDetail = function() {
        var model = ko.toJSON(currentUser());
        console.log(model);
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + 'api/xxxx/xxxxx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: model,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {}
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new userDetails());
});
```

Comment: You should make your `self`s local with `var`: `var self = this;`. You also need `self` in `var model = ko.toJSON(self.curretUser());`

Comment: thanks this solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've bound the `click` even on the `<input type="button"/>` element to a `saveuserDetail` function on the nested `curretUser` view-model, whereas you've actually located this function on the parent `userDetails` view-model.

```
<input type="button" value="save" data-bind="click:curretUser().saveuserDetail" />
```

Either change this binding to

```
<input type="button" value="save" data-bind="click:saveuserDetail" />
```

or relocate the `saveuserDetail` function to the `curretUser` view-model.

Also, you should favour the `textInput` binding for `<input/>` elements instead of the `value` binding. [Here is an explanation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html#note-1-textinput-vs-value-binding) of the difference.